# Strange behaviour writing accents in texmaker

Tags: texmaker

Sometimes, when I'm going to write accentuated letters such as `á`, just after pressing `´`, that symbol is written, instead of waiting for the next letter.

The strange thing is that it works well (for some time) if I switch window and switch back to texmaker (for example, alt+tab, or changing desktop with ctrl+alt+arrow, or closing and reopening texmaker).

I don't know if I have misconfigured texmaker, or if it is an operative system issue. I apologize if this is not the place to ask for this.

Though I can not give reproducible behaviour, this is what I have:

- linux mint 16 xfce
- installed texlive-latex-base
- installed texlive-lang-spanish
- installed texmaker
- configured texmaker editor to utf-8

with a base document generated with `wizard > new document`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
´a    % here I typed ´a
% here I switch and switch back
á     % here I also typed ´a
\end{document}
```

As I can workaround by switching and switching back to write any accentuated letter (and texmaker compiles words as `técnica` perfectly), it is not an important problem, but I'm curious why is this happenning.

#### EDIT

I have realised that the error happens when compiling (F1) and goes away when enter some menus like searching or replacing (Ctrl+f and Esc fixes it).

#### EDIT 2

As @dcmst suggested, installing `ibus-qt4` fixes it. See comments below.

Comment: Watch the language toolbar (make it visible from Control Panel if it's not) when you are switching windows. EDIT: Nonsense: you are on linux, nevermind

Comment: do you have ibus-qt installed? On my distro (Arch) it says it's needed for supporting accented characters.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that installing `ibus-qt4` has fixed it! Maybe you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved in the comments